# Cannot send large packets from esp

Tags: c#, tcp, arduino, esp8266, esp32

I have an Esp32 with a camera attached and want to send the images over tcp. I tried it using WifiClient (The standard tcp client implementation for wifi esp, i think). But when I am sending the image using client.write, only the first few thousand bytes are actually received by my C# server (I am for now writing the image to a file where I can see that basically the whole file is just null bytes). The total image is always around 90kb large, but I thought the TCP implementation would automatically split it into multiple packets. I then have tried to split it into multiple packets my self (splitting after 1000 bytes) and I was able to open the file (before all gallery programs said it was an unknown format), but it heavily impacted performance. I know the images are fine, since when I print them in hex over Serial and convert them to images, they work.

Here is the (simplified) code for the Camera module:

```
info[0] = (uint8_t)_jpg_buf_len;
info[1] = (uint8_t)((_jpg_buf_len & 0xFF00) >> 8);
info[2] = (uint8_t)((_jpg_buf_len & 0xFF0000) >> 16);

if(client.write(info, 3) < 0) fatal("Error writing the image size packet.");
if(client.write(_jpg_buf, _jpg_buf_len) < 0) fatal("Error writing image packet.");
```

And here is the part of the C# TCP Server that receives the packets:

```
NetworkStream stream = c.GetStream();

//The info buffer first written by the ESP containing the lowest 3 bytes of the image size integer.
byte[] buffInfo = new byte[4];
//Writes the lowest 3 bytes into the first 3 places in the buffer, since the highest byte is always 0
await s.ReadAsync(buffInfo , 0, 3);                  
int imgLen = (int)BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffInfo , 0);

//This always displays the correct lengths
Console.WriteLine("Received image with a length of {0}.", imgLen);
byte[] buffImg = new byte[imLen];
await s.ReadAsync(buffImg, 0, imLen);
//When the buffer is now written to a file, basically the whole image is null bytes and it cannot be viewed
```

Do I need to be manually splitting the huge buffers up? Or is there a more performant solution to this problem?

Comment: When you say *the first few thousand bytes are received by my server*, is it always precisely the same number? I'm curious what the number of bytes is. I couldn't find much in the way of documentation for the library, but the size parameter is a `size_t` which, on an ESP32, is probably a 32 bit value. So it implies it should work.

Comment: @lurker no, it is not. This is something in my code. I now changed some stuff and am able to receive the first image (without manually splitting it, so that was not the issue). It looks totally fine until a certain point, from which on it is highly corrupted. Then, there are still a lot of null bytes.

Comment: There was an issue with SSL sockets fixed with https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/pull/4820 that sounds like yours but you are using plain sockets?

Comment: Thanks you all for helping me, guys! I now figured it out, it was something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The esp is actually splitting the packets, but since the esp is way slower than the client, the client receives them as singular packets and when it tries to read the whole image, it cannot read the full length of bytes and fills the rest with null bytes. Then it tries to read the next image length, but the bytes read still belong to the image (but they just arrived now) and it gets really weird sizes. Here is my code I use now:

```
NetworkStream s = c.GetStream();
byte[] buffInfo= new byte[4];
await s.ReadAsync(buffInfo, 0, 3);
int imgLen= (int)BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffInit, 0);
byte[] buffImg = new byte[imgLen];
int remLen = imgLen;
while (remLen > 0) {
    remLen -= await s.ReadAsync(buffImg, imgLen- remLen, remLen);
}
```